# Asyncrhonous Firebase reference and referencing said reference values in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm am writing a React web app in which I utilize data pulled via Firebase and want to populate a series of React Objects based on a value pulled.

The idea is that firebase pulls in and updates the state with a snapshot which can be referenced in a child component.   The problem is that I've tried various attempts at loading the firebase response.

I suspect the reason why in DevTools the function does not appear to be firing is because it only fires once it receives an asynchronous response from the server... but it likely hasn't updated by the time the code in TextItem fires, causing the received text to be at null, throwing an error.

Here's the code:

```
/* Intialization 
code 
here
*/ 

const dbTextRef = firebase.database().ref('blogs/');


export default class App extends React.Component{
    state = {
        TextList : null,
    }

    //Set listener on data

componentDidUpdate(){   
            dbTextRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        this.setState({
            TextList : snapshot
        });
    });
}
    //In render, pass the state of the div down as props to the

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <TextAddContainer TextArray = {this.state.TextList} />

            </div>

        );
    }    
}

export class TextAddContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.RetrieveText = this.RetrieveText.bind(this);

    console.log("Props received in Text Container is: "+ props.TextArray);

    }

    //When loading or when a user adds new content, retrieve a list 
    //of all content from Firebase

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Dropdown />
                <TextItem TextArray = {this.props.TextArray} />
                <button onClick = {this.RetrieveText}>Refresh</button>
            </div>
            );
    }
}

const TextItem = (props) => {
    console.log("Prop received in individual item is:" + props.TextArray);

    const TextArray = props.TextArray;
    console.log(TextArray);
    const TextValues = Object.values(TextArray[0]);
    var returnArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i <= TextArray.length; i++){
        returnArray.push(<div key = {i}><p className = "CMSTextPreviewMenu">TextArray[0][i]</p></div>);
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Since Google's documents says that attaching a .on('value') response kicks off a data pull when first declared, I believe I can rule out the possibility that .on() isn't firing its resulting callback function.

Previously I once tried including a function within TextAddcontainer that would make a .once() call to firebase and pass that return value as a prop to , but that ended up being undefined for what I suspect is the same reason.

I've also attempted to use UNSAFE_ComponentWillMount() in my desparation to try to get Firebase to finish returning a response BEFORE the child components are rendered, but that hasn't worked either and felt like a dirty hack anyway.

What do you recommend?

Please let me know if I'm way off-base in my assumptions and what topics and vocabulary I should self-educate so that I can better model this issue in the future.

Comment: Hello, I'm from the FBI

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by placing the listener in the constructor and catching if values hadn't been loaded yet.  Thanks everyone!